# Need Help Creating Nested Contains Statement in a Calculated Field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, tableau-api

I am working in Tableau and I have a dimension titled Landing Page that contains all the URLs for my landing pages. I want to create a calculated field that takes the Landing Page dimension and looks for specific words within the string of the URL for the landing pages and then buckets/filters them under certain key words. I am assuming that I would do this with a IF CONTAINS statement, but I am not sure how to include my OR statements within the function.

This is what I am looking for:

-URLs that contain /employers/ should be labeled as Home

-URLs that contain /our-products/, /what-we-do/, /sign-up/, /what-is-employer-branding/, /informed-candidates/, or /community-partners/ should be labeled as Product

-URLs that contain /topics/ or /resources/ should be labeled as Resources

-URLs that contain /blog/ should be labeled as Blog

-URLs that contain /success-stories/ should be labeled as Success Stories

-URLs that /demos/ or /contact-sales/ should be labeled as Handraisers

```
IF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/employers/") then "Home"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/our-products/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/what-we-do/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/sign-up/")
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/what-is-employer-branding/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/informed-candidates/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/community-partners/") then "Product"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/topics/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/resources/") then "Resources"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/blog/") then "Blog"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/post-job/") then "Self Service"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/success-stories/") then "Success-Stories"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/demos/") 
OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/contact-sales/") then "Handraisers"
ELSE "Null" END
```

I am currently getting Blog, Home, Resources, Self Service, and Null to populate as rows or columns in Tableau, but the words Product, Success-Stories, and Handraisers are missing. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted your calculation and I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
IF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/employers/") 
    then "Home"
ELSEIF 
    (
     CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/our-products/") 
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/what-we-do/") 
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/sign-up/")
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/what-is-employer-branding/") 
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/informed-candidates/") 
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/community-partners/") 
     )
     then "Product"

ELSEIF 
   (
    CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/topics/") 
    OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/resources/") 
   )
   then "Resources"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/blog/") 
   then "Blog"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/post-job/") 
   then "Self Service"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/success-stories/") 
   then "Success-Stories"
ELSEIF 
    (
     CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/demos/") 
     OR CONTAINS([Landing Page], "/contact-sales/") 
    )
    then "Handraisers"
ELSE "Null" END
```

Possibly what is going on is your URL's contain multiple phrases like `/employers/sign-up`?

I would suggest to try and pull out this part of the URL and put it in it's own field.  EG use a regexp_extract calculation like this: `REGEXP_EXTRACT('http://google.com/employers/',  'http:\/\/google\.com(.*)')`.  The result would be `/employers/`.  This would probably help you figure out why you are not getting some of the results you expect.

If you can also supply some data samples (if this doesn't answer the question) I can work through that.

Comment: I ended up removing the hash marks that encased the strings that I was looking for, re-ran the function, and it appears to have worked.